# Making 'linkTo' active on two routes, not one

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have this kind of menu in my Ember application:

`template: search.hbs`

```
<div class="tabs">
    {{#linkTo "search.radio" activeClass="selected" tagName="span"}}{{ t "RadioStations" }}{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo "search.compilations" activeClass="selected" tagName="span"}}{{ t "Compilations" }}{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo "search.track.list" activeClass="selected" tagName="span"}}{{ t "Tracks" }}{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo "search.artist" activeClass="selected" tagName="span"}}{{ t "Artists" }}{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo "search.album" activeClass="selected" tagName="span"}}{{ t "Albums" }}{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo "search.all" activeClass="selected" class="last" tagName="span"}}{{ t "All" }}{{/linkTo}}
</div>
```

I have this kind of routing for my `search.tracks` (sorry for `CoffeeScript`, but i think it's understandable what's going on):

```
  @resource 'search.track', path: 'track', ->
    @route 'index', path: ''
    @route 'list', path: '/list'
```

One route displays tracks in block mode, other route displays them in table mode. I have both `SearchTrackIndexController` and `SearchTrackListController`.

What i need is, that the corresponding tab `{{#linkTo "search.track.list"}}` become active both on `search.track.index` and `search.track.list` route, while still being a link to `search.track.list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the solution is extremely simple.

```
{{#linkTo "search.track.list"  activeClass="selected" tagName="span" currentWhen="search.track"}}
```

This did exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `current-when` of `{{link-to}}` helper. This is available in the beta & canary builds.

[Demo bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/viyaz/1/edit)

Check out this [PR 3673](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3673)

Comment: Could work, but this is a bugfix on a production server, i cannot upgrade to a beta build just yet.

Comment: You can patch the implementation and remove the patch when you upgrade your app